# Create flip cart animation between two NSViews

Tags: swift, macos, animation, core-animation

Hi I want to create flip card animation between two full screen NSViews

but my animation didn't work as expected like in iOS

here is example of iOS working code

```
UIView.transition(from:self.upperView, to:self.lowerView,duration:1,options:[.transitionFlipFromRight])
```

On mac OS app i am trying add two NSViews stack on top of each other.

```
private lazy var lowerView:NSView = {
        let view = NSView()
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var upperView:NSView = {
        let view = NSView()
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
```

Thank I add 2 views to parent view of the viewcontroller with constraints.

```
private func addUpperView() {
        self.view.addSubview(upperView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            upperView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            upperView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            upperView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            upperView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),

        ])       
    }
    
    private func addLowerView () {
        self.view.addSubview(lowerView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            lowerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            lowerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            lowerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
            lowerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor)        ])

    }
```

All of this i am executing in on viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear() { 
addLowerView()
addUpperView()

 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) {
            FlipTransition().flip(from: self.upperView, to: self.lowerView)
        }

}
```

And this is my helper class for executing the animation.

```
import Cocoa

public final class FlipTransition: NSObject {
    
    private var srcView, dstView: NSView?
    
    private var duration: TimeInterval = 2
    
    public func flip(
        from srcView: NSView,
        to dstView: NSView,
        duration: TimeInterval = 2
    ) {
        
        self.duration = duration
        self.srcView = srcView
        self.dstView = dstView
        srcView.isHidden = false
        dstView.isHidden = true
        
        guard let superLayer = srcView.layer else {
            return
        }
                
        var transform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform3D.m34 = 1 / -1000

        let translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(
            superLayer.bounds.midX,
            superLayer.bounds.midY,
            .zero
        )

        superLayer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DConcat(
            transform3D,
            translation
        )
        
        animate(
            srcView,
            from: CATransform3DIdentity,
            to: CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / -2, 0, 1, 0)
        ) { f in
            self.startSecondStep()
        }
    }
    
    private func startSecondStep() {
        
        guard let srcView = srcView, let dstView = dstView else {
            return
        }
        
        srcView.isHidden = true
        dstView.isHidden = false
        animate(
            dstView,
            from: CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 1, 0),
            to: CATransform3DIdentity
        ) { f in
            self.finish()
        }
    }
    
    private func finish() {
        
        guard let srcView = srcView, let dstView = dstView else {
            return
        }
        
        srcView.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
        dstView.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
        
        [srcView, dstView]
            .compactMap(\.layer)
            .forEach { layer in
                layer.anchorPoint = .zero
            }
        
        srcView.superview?.layer?.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }
    
    
    private class AnimationDelegate: NSObject, CAAnimationDelegate {
        
        private let completion: (Bool) -> Void
        
        init(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
            self.completion = completion
        }
        
        func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) { }
        
        func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
            completion(flag)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func animate(
        _ view: NSView,
        from: CATransform3D,
        to: CATransform3D,
        completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
    ) {
        
        let dstRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        dstRotation.fromValue = from
        dstRotation.toValue = to
        dstRotation.duration = duration / 2
        dstRotation.fillMode = .forwards
        dstRotation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        dstRotation.delegate = AnimationDelegate(completion: completion)
        
        view.layer?.add(dstRotation, forKey: "flip")
    }
    
}
```

Can some one help me pls how to achieve the same animation like in iOS using UIView.transition

Comment: "didn't work as expected" Please tell us what is expected.

Comment: Hi @matt that it flips from one view to another like flip cart. In my sample the view on top just fades.